# Pretrained Tensorflow Model invalid argument error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, inference, pre-trained-model

I'm doing my project using tensorflow with pre-trained mobilenet_v2 model which can be found on https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

I wanted to get hidden layer values so I implemented this source code and I got an invalidargumenterror

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    im = Image.open('./sample/maltiz.png')
    im3 = im.resize((300, 300))

    image = np.asarray(im)[:,:,:3]

    model_path = 'models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/'

    meta_path = os.path.join(model_path, 'model.ckpt.meta')
    model = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)

    sess = tf.Session()
    model.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))

    data = np.array([image])
    data = data.astype(np.uint8)

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, shape=[None, None, None, 3])

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    for i in graph.get_operations():
        if "Relu" in i.name:
            print(sess.run(i.values(), feed_dict = { X : data}))
```

I got this error message

```
File "load_model.py", line 42, in <module>

    print(sess.run(i.values(), feed_dict = { X : data}))
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'image_tensor' with dtype uint8 and shape [?,?,?,3]

[[node image_tensor (defined at load_model.py:24) ]]
```

I printed out the placeholder and the shape of data.

placeholder was uint8 typed [?,?,?,3]
and image had a shape with [1,300,300,3]
I don't know what is the problem.

It looks like just perfect matching with the type on the error message.

**Please let me know what is the problem.**

Comment: Can you try with `np.array(image)` instead of np.array([image])

Comment: I just got the almost same error with previous one. (Shape unmatched) 
 ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (300, 300, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?, 3)'

Comment: Can you print the shape of data and it's type after the line `data = data.astype(np.uint8)` ?

Comment: uint8 `print(data.dtype)`
(1, 300, 300, 3) `print(data.shape)` Thanks

Comment: FYI, Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, 3), dtype=uint8) `print(X)`

Comment: Try this 
`tf.reset_default_graph()`
`print(x.name)`
`x=tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("Placeholder:0")`

Read the link given below, it has some useful comments.
Reference: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10632)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the predefined graph and restore the graph to the latest checkpoint, the graph is already defined. But when you do

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8, shape=[None, None, None, 3])
```

You are creating an extra node in the graph. and this node has nothing to do with the nodes you want to evaluate, nodes from `graph.get_operations()`  don't depend on this extra node but some other node, and since this other node does not get fed with values, the error says invalid arguments.

The correct way is to get the tensor that the nodes to be evaluated depend upon from the predefined graph.

```
im = Image.open('./sample/maltiz.png')
im3 = im.resize((300, 300))

image = np.asarray(im)[:,:,:3]

model_path = 'models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/'

meta_path = os.path.join(model_path, 'model.ckpt.meta')
model = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)

sess = tf.Session()
model.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))

data = np.array([image])
data = data.astype(np.uint8)

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
X = graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

for i in graph.get_operations():
    if "Relu" in i.name:
        print(sess.run(i.values(), feed_dict = { X : data}))
```

PS: I did try the above approach myself but there is some tensorflow (version 1.13.1) internal bug which stops me from evaluating all the nodes that have `Relu` in their names. But still some nodes can be evaluated this way.